# Is there any way to set default value to a property of Entity Framework Core entity when mapping to CosmosDB collection

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection `Collection-test` in Cosmos DB. My entity for the collection is:

```
public class Collection-test
{
    public string id { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}
```

My EF mapping is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Collection-test>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToContainer("Collection-test");
        entity.HasNoDiscriminator();
        entity.Property(e => e.isActive).HasConversion<bool>();
        entity.HasPartitionKey(x => x.id);
    });
```

My issue is: some of documents in the collection have no `isActive` key. So if `isActive` field is not nullable in the entity class, then null assignment causes an exception.

But if I use

```
public bool? isActive { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public bool isActive { get; set; }
```

the mapping works fine.

Could anybody find a way to assign default value if the field it is nullable in the entity class?

Comment: You're asking for a *replacement*, not a default value. One that will probably introduce quite a few bugs - that field is neither true nor false, it doesn't exist. That's what `null` is for. It means a value doesn't exist. If *the application's* business logic wants to treat `null` equal to `false`, it should make this explicit

Comment: If you really, really want to treat `null` as `false` you can replace the automatic property with one backed by a field, whose getter returns `false` if the field is null, eg `public bool IsActive { get => _isActive??false; set => _isActive=value;}`

Comment: yes if i use getter for  default value then it will work. But I was searching how to set it when we map the field

Comment: and the Boolean field is just an example and dont be specific to that. Any fields can be missing in NoSQL data base side.

Comment: Even worse - what would be the "default" in other types? Don't confuse how client tools and programming languages behave with how *data* behaves. Nothing says that a default is acceptable when a field is missing. If you store books, songs and videos in the same collection, what's the sensible default for a book's bitrate? Or number of channels? These properties have no meaning in a Book document

Comment: There's a reason ORMs have been called [The Vietnam of Computer Science](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/). Even when dealing with document databases, data and programming languages behave differently. ORMs can only go so far to cover these differences

Comment: Same type of missing feature if we want to map a dynamic field. Ex: if I use EFCore & Cosmos, and use a property as dynamic then mapping wont work . But especially in NoSQL how we are sure a field is int, string or an Array of objects ?

Answer (score 2):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Collection-test>()
        .Property(b => b.IsActive)
        .HasDefaultValue(false);
}
```

This is what mentioned in docs. You can check it further here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a replacement, not a default value. In databases, the default is the value that's stored when no other value is provided. When no value is available, `NULL` is used. NULL isn't a value, it means there's *no* value at all. If you want to return `false` when no value is available you're actually asking to replace the missing value with a very specific one.

Doing this can easily introduce errors. It will interfere with querying as well. Searching for `IsActive = False` is saying:

> fetch objects that have an `IsActive` field whose value is False

That won't return objects that just don't have an `IsActive` value. Even if you replace `NULL` with `false` you'll still have to query for `NULL`

If the application's business logic wants to treat null equal to false, it should make this explicit. One way to do this is to replace the automatic property with one backed by a nullable field whose getter replaces `null` with `false:

```
bool? _isActive;
public bool IsActive 
{ 
    get => _isActive??false; 
    set => _isActive=value;
}
```

Comment: your opinion is correct if we are dealing with relational database, but if you are mapping with Nosql data base then even some fields can be missing . But when you keep a field nullable in entity mapping side then nested lamda expressions will raise an exception since entity framework cannot generate the query from it.